# Delete object ID and enumerate new column

Tags: python, django, sqlite

In my Django admin I have a `TabularInLine` class. In the picture, each element of this class is numbered with it's own `ID`. How can I delete the text circled by red color on picture? And how I can create a new numbered column (from 1 to amount elements in table)?

[image]

This `TabularInLine` class has a foreign key to an other class (class `Part`). How I can to numerate that for each `FK` with the numbering (`my_id`) started from 1 as in the picture below?

[image]